# How can I make Bootstrap and jQuery work in CodeIgniter?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

I am new to Codeigniter and also to Bootstrap so when I tried to put the two together and also jQuery a problem arised.
I have the following structure:

- Views/Layout/content.php
- Views/home_view.php
- Controllers/home.php
- .htaccess

with the following coding:
Views/Layout/content.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Doc</title>
<link rel="sylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url("assets/css/bootstrap.min.css");?>">    
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url("assets/js/jquery.js");?>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"  src="<?php echo base_url("assets/js/bootstrap.min.js");?>"></script>

</head>
<body>

<div class="container">

 <div class="col-xs-6">


 </div>

 <div class="col-xs-6">

  <?php $this->load->view($content_view); ?>

 </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Views/home_view.php:

`<h1>Hello </h1>`
   `<h2>Content goes here </h2>`

Controllers/home.php:

```
class Home extends CI_Controller{

  public function index(){

   $data['content_view']="home_view";

   $this->load->view('Layout/content',$data);

   $this->load->helper('url');

  }

}
```

.htaccess:

```
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|assets|robots\.txt)
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

The above and below coding includes everything relevant I could find on other Stackoverflow posts, Codeigniter documentation and also other web pages. Lastly, I also made the following changes to application/config.php:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/project/';
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

When I open the home page in the browser, the text is displayed normally (without any font/aligning changes - as it would have been if bootstrap was enforced). Moreover, I checked with Inspect element/View page source and neither Safari nor Google Chrome display anything to let me know that the files are not working.
I downloaded the latest versions from jQuery (2.1.4) and Bootstrap (3.3.5).
What other code/setting must I change in order to view the Bootstrap/jQuery implemented and the home.php text displayed accordingly in browser?

Thank you very much in advance for your help!

Comment: Read this tutorial http://w3code.in/2015/10/how-to-edit-delete-and-update-data-without-refreshing-page-in-codeigniter/

Comment: Yes, this was the mistake.."sylesheet" instead of the right "stylesheet". Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this

```
<link rel="sylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url("assets/css/bootstrap.min.css");?>">
```

to

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url("assets/css/bootstrap.min.css");?>">
```

Comment: The both statements seem to be the same...maybe you skipped to make the change on the second or am I missing something...thanks.

Comment: you type rel="sylesheet" instead of rel="stylesheet"